# I'm creating a collatz formula calculator. I want to only print out the number of steps at the end not a line for each of the steps. How do I do this?

Tags: java

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int c0 = input.nextInt();
    int steps = 0;
    while (c0 != 1)
      while (c0 != 1) {
        int c1 = c0 % 2;

        if (c1 == 0) {
          c0 = (c0 / 2);
          steps = steps + 1;
          System.out.println(c0);
        } else {
          c0 = (3 * c0 + 1);
          System.out.println(c0);
          steps = steps + 1;
        }
           
        steps = steps - 0;    
        System.out.println("steps = " + steps);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly.

Comment: And just move your `println` to the end of your method.

Comment: `steps = steps - 0;` <- what was this meant to do?

Answer (score 1):

As was said in the comments, just move the print statement outside the loop. But why are you using two nested while loops and extra variables? It can be done as simply as the following.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int c0 = input.nextInt();
int steps = 0;
while (c0 != 1) {
    if (c0 % 2 == 0) {
        c0 /= 2;
    } else {
        c0 = 3 * c0 + 1;
    }
    steps++;
}
System.out.println("Total steps = " + steps);
```

In fact, you can replace everything within the while loop with:

```
c0 = c0 % 2 == 0 ? c0 / 2 : c0 * 3 + 1;
steps++;
```

Check out the [conditional operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) also referred to as the ternary operator.

Comment: Thank you so much to both of you. I'm new to Java, so I get stumped often. Thanks for helping!